# PHP: Getting sqlite_escape_string to work correctly. Allow apostrophes to be saved

Tags: php, arrays, string, escaping

The problem: when editing a language, you cannot add an apostrophe to the text field. If you do, the record will not be saved with the new edits.

The goal: Upon editing, allow these edits to include apostrophes and save correctly.

Currently: you can use numbers, letters, and symbols, but not apostrophes.

I tried this thinking it would work, but to no avail:

```
$val = (isset($airport_info[$airport_key])) ? sqlite_escape_string($airport_info[$airport_key]) : "";
```

Below is the original code.

```
<div class="inline_div_right">
  <table>
    <?php
      $j=1;
      $some_langs_hidden = 0;
      foreach(array_keys($fields) as $airport_key)
      {
        if(is_numeric($airport_key)) continue;
        if(preg_match("/name_/", $airport_key))
        {
        $lang_iso = substr($airport_key, -2);
        $val = (isset($airport_info[$airport_key])) ? $airport_info[$airport_key] : "";
        $row_visibility = "";
          if(!in_array($lang_iso, $used_languages))
          {
          $row_visibility = "hidden_class";
          $some_langs_hidden = 1;
          }
          $row_class = ($j%2 == 0) ? "shade1" : "shade2";
          ?>
          <tr class="<?php echo $row_class.' '.$row_visibility; ?>">
          <td class='ca_left_column'><?php echo $languages[$lang_iso]; ?></td>
          <td><input type='textfield' id='<?php echo $airport_key; ?>' name='<?php echo $airport_key; ?>' class='textfield_class_large' onkeypress="hideErrorMsg(); enterSubmission(event, fcn)" value='<?php echo $val; ?>'></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
            $j++;
          }
      }

    ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: If a record does not save, that sounds like a database error. Are you using a suitable SQLite function to test for, and report, error conditions?

Comment: Hi Halfer, no I am not. Do realize that I can save the edited record, as long as it does not include apostrophes.

Comment: Aha, the problem is in your HTML. Try `value='<?php echo addslashes($val) ?>'`. If an apostrophe gets into this string, it prematurely closes the attribute, and corrupts the remainder of the tag.

Comment: You should _always_ be checking for error conditions in your database code, in any case. Assume every call to your database system will fail, and then when it does, you'll already be catching it gracefully.

Comment: Well it seems addslashes literally adds slashes, where I want to only add apostrophes to the textfield you edit. I'm looking at the PHP docs now, and none of these similar methods seem suitable? As for the database stuff, I will keep that in mind and talk to my coworker about it :)

Comment: Yes, a backslash is how you escape an apostrophe. This is how a literal apostrophe is differentiated from the delimiting apostrophes/speech marks of an HTML attribute. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Defined a function:

```
function sqlSecurity($sql_string)
{
  $return_string = sqlite_escape_string($sql_string);
  $val = stripslashes($return_string);
  return $val;
}
```

Called this function in our processAJAX.php file, main line being:

```
 $query .= ", name_$lang_code = '".sqlSecurity($_REQUEST["name_$lang_code"])."'";
```

Then for the view value in the textfield:

```
value="<?php echo str_replace('"', '&quot;', $val); ?>"
```

Any constructive criticism is appreciated. The correct values are being returned in the database and displayed correctly in the browser.